# Vue3 Render Functions: Passing directives

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, virtual-dom

I'm trying to create a Confirmation Dialog component that works via a composable (I'm not sure how good/bad of an idea that is).

Thus far, I have the following code, which almost works. You will notice the `unmount` function is using Javascript which is incorrect because I'm then manipulating the real DOM vs the virtual DOM (and the entire app gets wiped out).

I guess my question is, how can I call this function (`confirm`), which takes in some properties and then render it and then unmount it cleanly?

```
import { h, render } from 'vue'

export default function confirmationDialog() {
    const confirm = ({ title, description, callback }) => {
        const parent = document.getElementById('app')

        const child = h(
            'div',
            {
                id: 'confirmation-dialog',
                class: 'custom-popup-container',
            },
            [
                h('div', { class: 'custom-popup' }, [
                    h('div', { class: 'popup-header' }, [
                        h('h2', { class: 'popup-title' }, title),
                        h(
                            'a',
                            {
                                class: 'popup-close',
                                onClick: () => unmount(),
                            },
                            [h('span', { class: 'icon-close' })],
                        ),
                    ]),
                    h('div', { class: 'popup-content' }, [
                        h('p', {}, description),
                    ]),
                    h('div', { class: 'pop-footer' }, [
                        h('div', { class: 'footer-btns' }, [
                            h(
                                'button',
                                {
                                    class: 'btn btn-lg btn-white',
                                    onClick: () => unmount(),
                                },
                                'Cancel',
                            ),
                            h(
                                'button',
                                {
                                    class: 'btn btn-lg btn-primary',
                                    onClick: () => {
                                        callback()
                                        unmount()
                                    },
                                },
                                'Confirm',
                            ),
                        ]),
                    ]),
                ]),
            ],
        )

        const unmount = () => {
            const target = document.getElementById('confirmation-dialog')
            parent.removeChild(target)
        }

        render(child, parent)
    }

    return { confirm }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do it using components. Something like this:

```js
const { createApp, h } = Vue;

const confirm = {
  props: ['show', 'title'],
  emits: ['close'],
  setup(props, context) {    
    return () =>     
      !props.show ? h('div') :
      h('div',
            {
                id: 'confirmation-dialog',
                class: 'custom-popup-container',
            },
            [
                h('div', { class: 'custom-popup' }, [
                    h('div', { class: 'popup-header' }, [
                        h('h2', { class: 'popup-title' }, props.title),
                        h('a',
                            {
                                class: 'popup-close',
                                onClick: () => {
                                        alert('Cancel')
                                        context.emit('close', false)
                                    },
                            },
                            [h('span', { class: 'icon-close' })],
                        ),
                    ]),
                    h('div', { class: 'popup-content' }, [
                        h('p', {}, context.slots.default),
                    ]),
                    h('div', { class: 'pop-footer' }, [
                        h('div', { class: 'footer-btns' }, [
                            h('button',
                                {
                                    class: 'btn btn-lg btn-white',
                                    onClick: () => {                                        
                                        alert('Cancel')
                                        context.emit('close', false)
                                    },
                                },
                                'Cancel',
                            ),
                            h('button',
                                {
                                    class: 'btn btn-lg btn-primary',
                                    onClick: () => {
                                        alert('Confirm')
                                        context.emit('close', true)
                                    },
                                },
                                'Confirm',
                            ),
                        ]),
                    ]),
                ]),
            ],
        )
  }
}

const App = {
  components: { confirm },
  data() {
    return { showDialog: false, result: null }  
  },
  methods: {
    show() { 
      this.showDialog = true
    },
    close(value) { 
      this.showDialog = false; 
      this.result = value 
    },
  }  
}

const app = createApp(App)
const vm = app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 2; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
showDialog: {{showDialog}}<br/>
result: {{result}}<br/>
<button @click="show()">confirm</button>
<hr/>
<confirm :show="showDialog" title="Please confirm" @close="close">Description</confirm>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

---

**UPDATE**

Here the same as functional component

```js
const { createApp, h } = Vue;

function confirm(props, context) {
    return h('div', 
      !props.show ? h('div') :
      h('div',
            {
                id: 'confirmation-dialog',
                class: 'custom-popup-container',
            },
            [
                h('div', { class: 'custom-popup' }, [
                    h('div', { class: 'popup-header' }, [
                        h('h2', { class: 'popup-title' }, props.title),
                        h('a',
                            {
                                class: 'popup-close',
                                onClick: () => {
                                        alert('Cancel')
                                        context.emit('close', false)
                                    },
                            },
                            [h('span', { class: 'icon-close' })],
                        ),
                    ]),
                    h('div', { class: 'popup-content' }, [
                        h('p', {}, context.slots.default),
                    ]),
                    h('div', { class: 'pop-footer' }, [
                        h('div', { class: 'footer-btns' }, [
                            h('button',
                                {
                                    class: 'btn btn-lg btn-white',
                                    onClick: () => {                                        
                                        alert('Cancel')
                                        context.emit('close', false)
                                    },
                                },
                                'Cancel',
                            ),
                            h('button',
                                {
                                    class: 'btn btn-lg btn-primary',
                                    onClick: () => {
                                        alert('Confirm')
                                        context.emit('close', true)
                                    },
                                },
                                'Confirm',
                            ),
                        ]),
                    ]),
                ]),
            ],
        )
    )
}

confirm.props = ['show', 'title']
confirm.emits = ['close']

const App = {
  components: { confirm },
  data() {
    return { showDialog: false, result: null }  
  },
  methods: {
    show() { 
      this.showDialog = true
    },
    close(value) { 
      this.showDialog = false; 
      this.result = value 
    },
  }  
}

const app = createApp(App)
const vm = app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 2; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
showDialog: {{showDialog}}<br/>
result: {{result}}<br/>
<button @click="show()">confirm</button>
<hr/>
<confirm :show="showDialog" title="Please confirm" @close="close">Description</confirm>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

Comment: If using a component, it wouldn't really make sense to use a render function. I was hoping to use a function (composable?) to do this so that I can do it from anywhere (ie, a js file).

Comment: You can create it as a [Functional Component](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#functional-components)

Comment: You think you could write me an example? @Tolbxela?

Comment: @RizaKhan Why don't you want simply use the component from anywhere?

Comment: This will be a simple confirmation dialog, so don't want something heavy for it.